# Multiselect in Redux Form with Create new tag option

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form

How do I use the Multiselect of React Widgets in Redux Form where I can allow the creation of new option as well which will be stored with redux form state. Redux form documentation do not have example with new tag creation option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, we need to make `allowCreate={true}` with `onCreate={(name) => this.input.push(name)}` both the attributes are necessary for the create tag option to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this package yet, but I don't think the package provides a functionality to allow tag creation as it is. 
Either you should implement it yourself, by providing an input for option creation and push them in to your options state object or you use another package like https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select which already implemented the desired functionality.

Comment: React Widget have this feature, also I am using Redux form which updates the state in the background so not sure how do I update state by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `onCreate={(name)=>data.push(name)}` because `this.input` doesn't contain push method.